# How to include Jquery library in vue js and how to call?

Tags: jquery, laravel, vue.js

i am using Vue js and laravel
So for frontend  I need Jquery library 
Which is i included directly but after that Jquery library not working.

Any suggested and Good way to include in Vue js application.
I Have Jquery Library 
jquery.lineProgressbar.js

How this called via Vue js

Advanced Thanks for all

Comment: beginner Thanks to you, how are you calling lineProgressbar?

Comment: Currently in my blade file 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/js/jquery.lineProgressbar.js') }}"></script>

Comment: Also calling ffunction in vue 
  mounted: function() {  
   $('#progressbar1').LineProgressbar({
    percentage: 25
   });
  }

Answer (score 1):

It is generally not recommended to integrate jQuery with VueJS, as they are likely to clash and overlap in functionality. In other words, what you can achieve with jQuery, you can achieve with VueJS (it's a front-end framework).

Having said that, if you're still interested to try and integrate jQuery with VueJS, I believe this article has the answers: https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/

Comment: i have to do lots of ui dashboard chaneg that"s why i am using Jquery library.

Comment: Also this article not telling me how to call Jquery file. I already invoke function via mounted but nothing  happen

Comment: Did you have a look at the JSBin included in the article - https://jsbin.com/bepikonube/2/edit?html,js,output . Try including the file as a script in your html, i.e. `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>`

Comment: <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

Comment: did it same way but that is not working.

Comment: Without any code and error logs, it is very difficult to help. Perhaps you can setup an example of what you're trying to achieve in a code playground/sandbox such as jsbin, jsfiddle, codepen, etc.

Comment: I  just want to know how to call any JS library in vue js in Laravel.